# R pamk use of clara

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pam

I am wondering how to choose the number of samples when using `pamk`

`pamk <- pamk(d, usepam=F)`

This way I use `clara` instead of `pam` however when I use `clara` `samples = 5` is default, but i change it

`clara = clara(d, k=6, samples = 1000)`

How do I use `pamk` to find optimal number of clusters whilst specifying how many samples is used when computing `clara`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, there's a `...` argument to `pfc::pamk` where you can pass arguments pased on to `clara`. So in your case, that would mean

```
pamk(d, usepam = FALSE, k = 6, samples = 1000)
```

See also page [95 of the manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpc/fpc.pdf) or `?pamk`.

Comment: In general does ... mean something similar?

Comment: @Olivia `...` is used to pass arguments from the top function to (one of) the bottom function(s). Anything you specify in pamk and is not explicitly mentioned in the argument list, is passed on the the function which is designed to accept `...`.